# How can I merge a DEM mosaic with an overlapping bathymetry raster (while keeping only the portions of each that I want)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, raster-calculator, merge, mosaic

I am tasked with merging a bathymetry raster with a mosaic raster I created from ArcGrid DEM Tiles downloaded from the National Map, for an areal extent spanning the Coastal Lowlands Aquifer System.

The bathymetry raster is needed because the the Mapper only has information for so far off the coast. In order to fill in the Gulf portion of the grid area, the DEM will have to be merged with bathymetry (the raster was created from the GCOOS-STRM30Plus v6 bathymetry dataset).

The bathymetry ALMOST completely aligns with the rectangular extent of the DEM mosaic but not entirely.

Right now the DEM is a rectangle that has values on land, and is completely black as it extends to the ocean.
In contrast the bathymetry raster has values in the ocean (obviously) and is completely white where the land is.

The output I want to achieve is a merged bathymetry/DEM raster, where I keep the DEM values on land and the Bathymetry in the ocean - and somehow blend the contact between them.

I've tried Mosaic to New Raster and so far, no outputs have turned out correctly.
I'm considering using Raster Calculator but I'm not entirely sure what to input to get the results I want. I only need the portion of the bathymetry raster that  portrays the ocean (the actual bathymetry data) and the portion of the DEM mosaic that displays the coastal lowlands.

Is there a way to clip the rest out using the raster calculator and then merge?